Replacing an expression with pre-defined function
I am asking Mathematica to do a long calculation with functions I am defining at the beginning of the script. Because the resulting expressions are long, I want to replace them with the functions I have defined previously. Is there a way to replace resulting expressions with a pre-defined function?
For example, consider the following. I define a function f:
f[x_] := x^3

and suppose that whatever calculation I want to do results in
x^3 y^6

Is there a way to force mathematica to write this expression as f[x] f[y^2] or f[xy^2]?
Thank you for the help!

x^3  y^6 /. x_^(n_ /; Mod[n, 3] == 0) :> f[x^(n/3)]  evaluates to: f[x] f[y^2]

@DanielHuber I was assuming that f was previously given DownValues, in which case your construction would just eventually evaluate and result in the original x^3 y^6 expression.

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! I think this might generally be a difficult thing to achieve. Is there any particular reason why you are not making your calculations with symbolic functions, such as f[x], without defining them?

Thank you for your comment. I actually did something similar in the end though it wasn't quite trivial as I needed the derivative of f[x]. I expressed the derivative in terms of f[x].
